# php regex - can't find the error

Tags: php, regex

Just one simple, specific question:
I've got the string `{var1}12345{var2}`, and I want to get the variable names used.

```
if (preg_match("/{([a-zA-Z0-9]*)}/g", $url, $matches)) {
    print_r($matches);
}
```

If I remove the global flag, it works, but I only get the first variable, as expected. Why isn't it working with a global flag? It works when I'm testing it with the [Regex Tester](http://www.gethifi.com/tools/regex)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [PHP: preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php):

> preg_match() returns the number of times pattern matches. That will be either 0 times (no match) or 1 time because **preg_match()  will stop searching after the first match**. preg_match_all()  on the contrary will continue until it reaches the end of subject. preg_match() returns FALSE  if an error occurred.

Comment: Aha! Wonder why they made it that way. Couldn't `preg_match()` return the number of hits on global searches too, it would still be "falsy" if there were no hits...Hmm.. Anyways. Thanks (:

Answer (score 2):

Use [preg_match_all](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) to fetch several matches:

```
if (preg_match_all("/{([a-zA-Z0-9]*)}/", $url, $matches)) {
    print_r($matches[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick (in case you need variables in format *{name}*):

```
$url = "{var1}12345{var2}";

if (preg_match_all("/{[a-zA-Z0-9]*}/", $url, $matches)) {
    print_r($matches);
}
```